# c# How To test Inheritance of an Abstract class with protected methods with xunit

Tags: unit-testing, c#-3.0, xunit.net

Assume that I have a public Class A and an Abstract class B such that B only contains protected methods. Now let A inherit from B.

Now my question is how do I(or should I) test if A inherits from B.

Comment: If you have an instance of `A`, you can use the `is` operator.

Comment: @Mike Caron / @user251709: Are you trying to test whether a class inherits from another (Mike's interpretation) or are you trying to test against protected methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using polymorphism, you will for sure be able to do as follows:

```
public class ClassB {
    protected MethodB() {
    }
}

public class ClassA : ClassB {
}


[TestFixture()]
public class TestA {
    [Test()]
    public void IsInstanceOfB() {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(ClassB), a);
    }
}
```

That is using NUnit, I guess there might be a similar approach with xUnit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the visibility of those protected methods. You won't be able to call them directly in your unit test. On the other hand you could write a class C in your unit test which inherits from A and which expose some public methods for the purposes of the test. Those public methods will simply call the protected methods you are trying to test.